# rotated text that is aligned to the top left corner outside of the image?

Tags: html, css, image, text, alignment

I was wondering what would be the most efficient way to place a rotated text directly outside the image's top left corner? Please keep in mind that I would like it if the height of the text box aligns with the height of the image, and the image scale will vary (tall images, short image, wide images, etc.)

Here is a visual of what I would like to achieve:
[image]

How might I do this? Thank you in advance!

Whoops, forgot to add the jsfiddle. You can view it [here!](http://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/sx6mem8j/)

```css
.image.information {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  margin:0;
  top:45%;
  left:100%;
  height:100%;
  -webkit-transition:all 250ms linear;
  -o-transition:all 250ms linear;
  transition:all 250ms linear;
  transform:rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
.image-wrap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.image-inner img {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-wrap">
  <img class="image-inner" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyMHW.jpg" alt="" />
  <div class="image information">
    information<br/>
    informa<br/>
    info
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: absolute positioning will help you. But I would include that in the picture itself instead of text as it's the part of the image.

Comment: Whoops! Sorry folks, heres the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/sx6mem8j/

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using CSS3 transforms, but requires an extra element in your DOM:

```
<div class="image-wrap">
    <img class="image-inner" src="http://media.creativebloq.futurecdn.net/sites/creativebloq.com/files/images/2013/08/korea5b.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="image information">
      <div class="info-inner">
        information
        <br/>informa
        <br/>info
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now with some absolute-positioning magic:

```
.image.information {
    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 75px;
    background: #ccc;
}
.info-inner {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; 
    left: 50%; 
    margin-top:-75px;
    margin-left: -75px;
    height:55px;
    width: 150px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.image-wrap {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
img.image-inner {
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: 75px;
}
```

Note that there's no simple way to have vertically-centered text without specifying an explicit text height. In this case I have chosen 55px. It will stretch to match the height of any image you specify.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zephod/ckqcLsbv/2/